# Set initial value of select2 from ajax string

Tags: jquery, ajax, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I'm using select2 v. 4.0.3

I have two fields on my form that once shown, an ajax call is made to populate the form data.

When the ajax call is made and on success, I want to populate the select2 boxes based on the values from "left_options" and "right_options" which are the two fields in my database that hold integer strings like this:  25,0      or  3,41,4

```
 //get all the record info and fillfields if in update mode
 $.ajax({
 url: "ajax_quick_get_value.php",
 type: "get",
 data: {
     table: 'invoice_hearing_aids',
     field: 'id',
     field_equals: $('#modal_form_invoice_hearingaids #hearing_aids_id').val()
 },
 dataType: 'json',
 success: function (response) {
//response here if data response

if (response) {

 //loop through the data and fill form fields based on id's
    $.each(response, function (index, value) {
        if(index != 'left_options' || index != 'right_options') {
            $('#modal_form_invoice_hearingaids #hearing_aids_' + index).val(value);
        }

        if(index == 'left_options') {
            var left_current_string = value;

            //will throw an error if it's null, so check first
            if (left_current_string != null) {
                var left_array = new Array();
                var left_array = left_current_string.split(',');

                $('#modal_form_invoice_hearingaids #hearing_aids_left_options').select2('val', left_array);
            }

        }

        if(index == 'right_options') {
            var right_current_string = value;

            //will throw an error if it's null, so check first
            if (right_current_string != null) {
                var right_array = new Array();
                var right_array = right_current_string.split(',');

                $('#modal_form_invoice_hearingaids #hearing_aids_right_options').select2('val', right_array);
            }
        }

    });
```

I'm able to confirm that the JSON data being returned from my ajax call has values for both left_options and right_options that are separated by a comma.

Only the first value from the options string is being populated into the select2 boxes.  Everything else after that is not populated.

```
 $('#modal_form_invoice_hearingaids #hearing_aids_left_options').select2('val', left_array)
```

I think the problem is in the above code somehow?  Same thing for the right_options code.

I feel like this worked, but suddenly stopped for some reason.  I use Chrome.

Here is how I populate my select2 with the options dynamically (just showing the right_options one here):

```
 <div class="form-group">
                <label class="control-label"></label>
                <select id="hearing_aids_right_options"  name="right_options[]" class="form-control hearing_aid_options" multiple style="width: 100%">
                <?php 
if($company->find_hearing_aid_options()) { 
$options = $company->hearing_aid_options(); 
foreach ($options as $option) { 
    echo '<option value="' .  $option->id . '">' .  $option->name . '</option>';
     };
};
 ?>
 </select>
```

I'm not sure if I need to supply more code, but I can.  Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to construct the data in the correct way on the server side so it returns an array of `key:value` pairs inside of an array named `items[]`. Furthermore, `select2` has it's own thoughts regarding handling data in the success of an ajax request, and therefore you should utilize the libraries implementation, for example:

```
$('select').select2({
     ajax: {
        url: "ajax_quick_get_value.php",
        dataType: 'json',
        delay: 250,
        data: function (params) {
          return {
            q: params.term, // search term
            page: params.page
          };
        },
        processResults: function (data, params) {
          params.page = params.page || 1;

          return {
            results: data.items,
            pagination: {
              more: (params.page * 30) < data.total_count
            }
          };
        },
        cache: true
      },
      escapeMarkup: function (markup) { return markup; },
      minimumInputLength: 1,
      templateResult: formatItems, 
      templateSelection: formatItemSelection
    });
});
```

Now the only thing you'll need to worry about is the 2 functions `formatItems` and `formatItemSelection`.

You can just implement something simple for these, like:

```
function formatItems(item) {
    return item.name;
}
```

and

```
function formatItemSelection (item) {
    return item.name;
}
```

That's it. Now you just need to make sure, on the server side, it's returned correctly in such a way that it's a proper JSON response as described above:

```
return json_encode([
    'items' => $myItemsArray
]);
```

Then you just need to return an array of objects that have an `id` property and a `name` property at the minimum.

Comment: So on my server, I have to have an array that has id and name for left_options and right_options fields? What if I change the name of the options? For instance, I decide to call it something else later.  I'd have to go through all records and rename the 'name' part of the json record, correct?  Right now, I'm just storing the id's as a comma separated string in left_options, right_options.  Then I am trying to populate the select2 based on these ids and options that I dynamically load from my database.

Comment: @chris.cavage You can choose whatever you want to utilize in the `formatItems` and `formatItemSelection` functions. I just choose name for simplicity. But you would need to maintain that for the future, as well

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me by changing the code to:

```
 $('#modal_form_invoice_hearingaids #hearing_aids_left_options').val(left_array).trigger("change");
```